# How to animate js turtle fractals?

Tags: javascript, turtle-graphics

I need to draw fractal using js [turtle library](https://github.com/bjpop/js-turtle) so, the fractal is animated until it is drawn totally like the python turtle example [here](http://blog.klipse.tech/python/2017/01/04/python-turtle-fractal.html)

I've tried in the command [here](https://rawgit.com/wrschneider99/js-turtle/master/turtle.html). There's a function called `animate` in the docs but I'm not able to use it, it only waits for some time then draw the fractal without any animation.

I type in the command input `animate(demo, 1000)`

Is there any suggestion?

if I can't use animation in js turtle Is there another fast easy library that can do the job of drawing fractals?!

Comment: Show us the code you've tried. You will probably need to wait on each step of the drawing process. It seems you only wait once (or all at the same time).

Comment: @JensV, I typed it misleading but updated now. I just downloaded the library with its starter code and tried that. You can try it here https://rawgit.com/wrschneider99/js-turtle/master/turtle.html

Comment: The `animate` in the library just uses `setInterval`. That means the movement of the action isn't actually *animated*. It just waits and performs the action. While it waits, execution continues though. To get the same behaviour as your python example, you can probably look into JS async await to make the job easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `animate()` correctly.  You can't just apply it to a finished program and expect its behavior to change.  Instead, you need to incorporate it into the program.  There should be a function that draws a portion of the animation each time it's called.  Then have it called over and over by `animate()`.  Rewritting your example:

```
function square(side) {
    repeat(4, function () {
        forward(side);
        right(90);
    });
}

var s = 100

function draw() {
    square(s);
    right(36)

    s -= 10

    if (s < 0) {
        s = 100
        clear()
    }
}

function demo() {
    hideTurtle();
    colour(0, 0, 255, 1);
    animate(draw, 500);
}
```

Invoke it via `demo()`, don't call `animate()` on it.  It's basic animation unit is the *square*.  If you want to see the squares being drawn, then you need to redesign the code to make the basic animation unit the side of a square (i.e. *line*.)